# Read ASCII data into R by specified column lengths

Tags: r, database

I have a large ASCII file that looks something like this if you open it in a text editor:

11112223423 4434  555534 5533         54534 5354 5532 434 4  43434 
23424234    34    4534    34453    345345345  345344           344
43423453453 43444 99098 234090       4354550  345399  43453 9900 4

I have been given a mapping of the columns. For example:  The first variable sits in columns 1-9.  The second column sits in 104-105. And so on.

Is there an easy way to read this type of data into R so that I end up with a data.frame?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can used the function `laf_open_fwf` from `LAF` package.

Comment: I'm afraid that it isn't an easy task to do in R. Maybe `awk` is a better tool to format this file in a way that R may read it more easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used the standard `read.fwf()` for this kind of thing.

I also like `read_fwf()` from the readr package. For example:

```
#create some dummy fixed-width-field data
fixed_width_data <- "line1  field1 datafield2 dataetc\nline2  field1 datafield2 dataetc\n"

#specify the data columns
field_info <- fwf_widths(c(7, 11, 11, 3), col_names=c("line_number", "field1", "field2", "fieldn"))

#read it in
parsed <- read_fwf(fixed_width_data,  field_info)
```

To specify start/end positions for the columns of data, you can use `fwf_positions()` instead of `fwf_widths()`:

```
#create some dummy fixed-width-field data
fixed_width_data2 <- "line1  field1 datafield2 dataTEXT TO SKIPetc\nline2  field1 datafield2 dataTEXT TO SKIPetc\n"

#specify the data columns using start and end positions
field_info2 <- fwf_positions(start=c(1, 8, 19, 42), end=c(5, 18, 29, 44), col_names=c("line_number", "field1", "field2", "fieldn"))

#read it in
parsed2 <- read_fwf(fixed_width_data2,  field_info2)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response!  Do you know if there is a way to specify the start and end position without fwf_widths?  the data that I have has gaps. for example: I don't know what sits between columns 9 and 104.  I am assuming that this is just white space.

Comment: You can do this by using fwf_positions() instead of fwf_widths(). I've added an example to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in base R using `read.fwf`  (fixed width fields)
I wrote a file with your single line of input and got:

```
FullFile = read.fwf("Test.txt", widths=c(9,94,2))
Interesting = FullFile[,c(1,3)]
Interesting
         V1 V3
1 111122234 42
```

Note that I am reading the columns to skip into a variable and then just discarding that variable.